# for teaching French

Tags: meaning, gerunds

a. Those gentlemen were sent to our school for teaching French.

b. Those gentlemen came to our school for teaching French.

Are these sentences grammatically correct and meaningful?

Comment: If you're asking about the gramaticality of some sentences, then be sure you understand the meaning first. Or if you're asking about the meaning of some sentences, be sure the grammar is good. You're asking two questions in one, which is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4):

Those sentences are grammatically correct but are unlikely to be used by English speakers. The object of "for" can be some kind of misdeed. (For example: "She received a ticket for speeding.") It therefore sounds as though those gentlemen went to the school as a kind of punishment because they'd taught French!

We can instead say:

> Those gentlemen were sent to our school for the purpose of teaching French.
> Those gentlemen came to our school for the purpose of teaching French.

However, those sentences are a bit lengthy. As you note, it would be more common to say:

> Those gentlemen were sent to our school [[in order]] to teach French.
> Those gentlemen came to our school [[in order]] to teach French.

With all of these sentences, the gentlemen will teach French, not learn it.